# Laravel 5 Deleting a one-to-many relationship

Tags: laravel, relationship, one-to-many, sql-delete, cascade

I have two tables:
 - Products
 - Themes

Products belong to a Theme - Themes has many Products.

I want to delete a theme and remove it's association with any Products. In a perfect world deleting a theme would reset the related Products' theme_id to NULL. In my Products table I have tried ->onDelete('cascade') but this deletes both the Theme and corresponding Products. If I do not implement ->onDelete('cascade') I get this error:

QLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`acme`.`products`, CONSTRAINT `products_theme_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`theme_id`) REFERENCES `themes` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE) (SQL: update `products` set `theme_id` = , `updated_at` = 2015-12-28 20:20:05 where `id` = 1)

Any suggestions would be super helpful. Thank You!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to define your product foreign key onDelete to set null and also the foreign key field as nullable

```
  Schema::create('products', function(Blueprint $t) {
        ...
        $t->integer('theme_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
        ...

        $t->foreign('theme_id')->references('id')->on('themes')
            ->onDelete('set null');
    });
```